# Page curl modal segue : leave bottom bar on screen

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, segue, page-curl

I develop an app for iOS 5+ with storyboards (and ARC). I have a view controller with no status bar, a top navigation bar, a map in the middle, and a bottom toolbar with a button at the bottom right. I've linked the button to a modal VC via a page curl segue.

My problem is I would like the page curl effect to apply **only** to the map (just as iOS 5's map), or at least **not** to the bottom toolbar, so I can present/dismiss the modal VC with the same button of the bottom bar (I want it to be persistent). Right now, I can present it by pressing the button, but the toolbar goes up halfway of the screen with the whole view. I can dismiss it by touching the upper-left side of the screen but it's not really user friendly.

I can add the toolbar to the modal view controller, but that doesn't look nice...

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick thought for you as I stumbled on this while looking for something else, but I would consider:

- Putting the top section of the screen within a container view, then presenting the modal view from that. It will leave the bottom (toolbar area) clear.
- Alternatively, instead of using the standard segue you could implement your own page curl, and/or using some of the open source projects that demonstrate how to do this.

You probably solved this long ago but perhaps this helps someone :)

Comment: Thanks, I worked my way around this by changing the app workflow, but since you're giving possible solutions, I'll accept this !